# Are there any Easter eggs or hidden areas in Bad Piggies?

Tags: ios, bad-piggies

I see the levels in Bad Piggies are littered with what could be hidden areas or treasures. They look nearly impossible or very difficult to reach. Anyone had any luck reaching any of these areas?

Answer (score 2):

I've retrieved all the skulls and nothing happened. There's only "secret" level when you find 10 skulls. I also have all stars in all levels (even the 5 sandbox) and nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of levels, there are hidden skulls that can be retrieved.  These skulls usually have to be retrieved by making a different contraption than that that would complete the level.  Make sure to zoom out and look around at the beginning of each level.

Besides the unlockable levels with the star requirements though, that's it.  I've tried (and succeeded) in hitting the message bottles and other random objects in the sand, but nothing has happened.

Once you retrieve all the skulls, a hidden level will be unlocked.